# teleop_base.cpp:37:21: erro fatal: joy/Joy.h:

Tags: ros, teleop-base, rosaria, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ALL

I'm trying to follow tutorial for installing "Rosaria" and when I do "rosmake" package "teleop_base" this can not find the file "Joy.h"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29202/teleop_base.cpp:37:21:-erro-fatal:-joy/joy.h:/) by [Macasten](https://answers.ros.org/users/1923/macasten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short Answer: This is due to the `teleop_base` being deprecated for a while.

Longer Answer: The Joy message is no longer in the `joy` package, but has instead been moved to `sensor_msgs`.  You could probably update `teleop_base` to reflect theses changes (the manifest.xml and the actual source files will have to be updated at a minimum).

Probably the better answer is to write a simple "glue" node that will change the Joy messages that your device (ps3joy, etc) puts out, and changes them into appropriately scaled Twist messages published on /cmd_vel.

The other option is to use a pre-made generic teleop node, like https://github.com/skynetish/teleop

---

**Related Questions**

- http://answers.ros.org/question/9207/teleop_base-deprecated-need-generic-teleop-package
- http://answers.ros.org/question/12744/importerror-no-module-named-joymsg

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2